# How to place this Label and Image with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to learn Xamarin forms and wish to try to do the following:

[image]

I'm thinking that I need to use a `RelativeLayout` but I'm struggling to understand *how* to use the provided tools. All the examples I'm reading say to use things like `LayoutFlags` and `LayoutBounds` (like [this nice demo](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-absolutelayout-recipe) and [also this one](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-relativelayout-recipe/)).

But no one is explaining *how* we should be using them.

Can someone please explain (bonus points if they provide an image with helper lines, etc) how I can do what I'm trying in that image?

`Image: it's like it's anchored to the bottom right corner`.

`Label: it's like it's centered .. and pushed down from the top about 20% odd..`

Comment: For putting the label inside the red box refer to this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315473/how-to-adjust-a-label-inside-of-a-image-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

You have some nice examples here: [SyntaxIsMyUI](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-relativelayout-recipe/). There you can do it relative to your parent and parent.Width for example.

Else you can easily get your screensize according to this: [Xamarin.Forms Kickstarter](http://www.xforms-kickstarter.com/#referring-to-the-screen-size)

Good luck!

---

Update:

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage ()
    {
        Label label = new Label { 
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            Text = "Label",
            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
        };
        BoxView image = new BoxView { 
            BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua,
        };
        BoxView frame = new BoxView { 
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            HeightRequest = 2000, //this will be ignored in relLayout
        };

        RelativeLayout relLayout = new RelativeLayout ();                   //create your relative layout which will be your parent
        relLayout.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;                              //this will only be full screen if this is your only View

        relLayout.Children.Add (label,                                      //add the children of it
            Constraint.RelativeToParent ((Parent) => Parent.Width / 4),     //left side of label a quarter in on screen
            Constraint.RelativeToParent ((Parent) => Parent.Height / 5),    //pushed down a fifth (20%) on the screen
            Constraint.RelativeToParent ((Parent) => Parent.Width / 2));    //Width is half screen size

        relLayout.Children.Add (frame,                                      //what will be a frame around picture
            Constraint.RelativeToParent ((Parent) => Parent.Width / 2),     //left side begin in the middle of screen along x-axis
            Constraint.RelativeToParent ((Parent) => Parent.Height - 60),   //top side 60 dp from bottom of the view (parent, this case entire screen)
            Constraint.RelativeToParent ((Parent) => Parent.Width / 2-10),  //Width is half screen - 30 dp to fit inside the frame
            Constraint.Constant (50));                                      //Height set to exactly 50 dp 

        relLayout.Children.Add (image,                                      //your image
            Constraint.RelativeToView (frame, 
                new Func<RelativeLayout, View, double> ((prelLayout, pframe) => frame.X + 5)), //inside the frame by 10 db
            Constraint.RelativeToView (frame,
                new Func<RelativeLayout, View, double> ((prelLayout, pframe) => frame.Y + 5)),  //10 dp inside frame
            Constraint.RelativeToView (frame,
                new Func<RelativeLayout, View, double> ((prelLayout, pframe) => frame.Width - 10)),//Width is same as frame - 10 dp (5 on each side)
            Constraint.RelativeToView (frame,
                new Func<RelativeLayout, View, double> ((prelLayout, pframe) => frame.Height - 10)));//Height set to same as frame height-10 to add the 5 dp inside the frame

        this.Content = relLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pierre - thanks for taking the time to help answer my Q. I've already linked to that webite/sample demo's ... but that site doesn't explain how to use the methods. He/she just uses them and expects us to understand the usage. I'm hoping for a cleaner explanation of what these terms means : such as `relative to your parent` etc.. Preferably with a nice grid-pricture to _really_ explain the terms used.

Comment: Hi @Pure.Krome updated with code example to try explain little better to achieve your picture (plus a not-so-good looking-fram around your picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
      img = new Image { Source = "a.png" ,Aspect=Aspect.AspectFill };

        txt = new Label { Text = "0",FontSize=30, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, TextColor = Color.Black };



grid = new Grid { 
           HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
             };
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.Children.Add(img);

        grid.Children.Add(txt);
    Content = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor=Color.White,
            Children = {
             grid,
```