# How to adjust a label "inside" of a image Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to put a label inside of my image, I couldn't use a `Margin` property, because some reason it's not working, untill now I have this :[image]

And what I want is this :

[image]

XAML :

```
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="something" TextColor="Black"/>
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="spin.png"/>
 </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need a `Grid` instead of a `StackLayout` (notice how both the `Label` and the `Image` are in the same row and column):

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Center"
      VerticalOptions="Center">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Image HorizontalOptions="Center"
         Source="spin.png"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="0"/>
  <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
         Text="something"
         TextColor="Black"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Because the `Label` is listed beneath the `Image` in the XAML code above, the `Label` will be drawn on top of the `Image`.

You also could have used an `AbsoluteLayout`, which is another layout that is good at layering things.